# Drupal 10 custom block with Bootstrap 5 dropdown button code - dropdown not functioning

Tags: drupal, bootstrap-5

I have a custom block in Drupal 10 with the Bootstrap 5 theme and I'm trying to create a functional Bootstrap 5 dropdown button on it. It renders fine but the dropdown function does nothing when clicked. Is there something about Drupal 10 that would affect it? Here's the code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks for your time and thoughts

Comment: How are you adding the above code? If entering it via a field's textarea input, some of the classes and attributes could be being filtered out depending on your input type (basic html, full html, etc.). Check the pages rendered html to make sure it is as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...almost.  I created a vanilla Text Format and used it on the block where I had the code.  It works as expected now I'm just not sure what the difference between the default Text Format and the new one is.

Comment: This should be added as a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that nothing has been changed in the Bootstrap5 theme, and the Bootstrap JavaScript file is loading in the client. I had a similar issue on a site I upgraded.

Check your `Text Format` settings for that field, and in the site config. By default, "Rich Text" will have `Limit allowed HTML tags and correct faulty HTML` enabled, then inside that text format setting it has `<button id class>` limitations/filter set for a `<button>`, therefore your button attributes of `type` and more importantly `data-bs-toggle` will not be sent in the rendered HTML output. Without that, Bootstrap won't know what to toggle, but in code, Bootstrap won't attach and event listener because of the missing `data` attribute it needs to make the action happen.